# PHP formula resulting in fatal error/not working

Tags: php

Hoping someone here can help, as I am currently out of my depth. So I am trying to cannibalize some pre-existing code to do a simple bit of maths for me. Basically I want to check if there is data in two fields, and if so to do the formula and then output the result into a field.

```
if (!empty($insurance["premium"] && $insurance['term'])) {
    $insurancep = $insurance["premium"] * ($insurance['term'] *12);
}
echo $insurancep;
```

I am new to php and I cannot understand why this is resulting in a fatal error/not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: a) what's the exact error, b) which line is throwing it, c) what values are in your fields and d) what output were you expecting? We haven't got enough info to solve your problem, only to guess. If you're going to do maths on the values, checking they exist isn't enough, you need to check they're numeric as well.

Comment: `!empty($insurance["premium"] && $insurance['term'])` this is probably not doing what you expect, basically you do a logical conjunction of premium and term (which either results in true or false) and then check if that is not empty. But I assume the basic problem is that one of the two keys doesn't exist in the array. Can you show us the var_dump of $insurance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (!empty($insurance["premium"] && $insurance['term'])) {
    $insurancep = $insurance["premium"] * ($insurance['term'] *12);
}

echo $insurancep;
```

is incorrect. http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php - is the link to `empty`. It should be written like this:

```
if (!empty($insurance["premium"]) && !empty($insurance['term'])) {
    $insurancep = $insurance["premium"] * ($insurance['term'] *12);
}

echo $insurancep;
```

off of ADyson's comment

`ideally it would check that the values are numeric too, since the code is going to multiply them`

```
if (
    !empty($insurance["premium"]) && is_numeric($insurance["premium"]) 
    !empty($insurance['term'])    && is_numeric($insurance["term"])
) {
    $insurancep = $insurance["premium"] * ($insurance['term'] *12);
}
```

if you're passing numbers and strings however, parse var like:

`(int)$insurance['term']` to declare the vartype as integer (though I recommened passing the datatype you intend to use)

Comment: ideally it would check that the values are numeric too, since the code is going to multiply them

Comment: @ADyson thats a shout

Comment: have an upvote for the edit, although regarding the very last bit, there's no guarantee the value would be parseble as an int. I don't see why it couldn't be legitimately be either a float or an int.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to close your first parenthesis after $insurance['premium'].

```
if (!empty($insurance["premium"]) && !empty($insurance['term'])) {
    $insurancep = $insurance["premium"] * ($insurance['term'] *12);
}
```

With the `empty` function, you can't test two variables at once, you have to test them one by one.